# Display tags & categories seperatly

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

When I called `the_taxonomies()` function it shows me both tags and categories. I need tags to show from `the_tags()` function. At the moment I haven't included `the_tags()` but shows me the tags through `the_taxonomies()`.

Because of this I'm unable to style them separately.

[image: image showing my problem in detail]

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=blog'); ?> 
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content("<span class=more-linkbl>Read more</span>"); ?>
    <div class="blog-misc">Date: <?php the_date();?> <?php the_taxonomies(); ?></div>
    ...
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: <?php query_posts( 'post_type=blog'); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>



<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>


<?php the_content("<span class=more-linkbl>Read more</span>"); ?>

<div class="blog-misc">Date: <?php the_date();?> <?php the_taxonomies(); ?> </div>

Comment: "Post" = update your question with an "Edit".

Answer (score 0):

Remove `the_taxonomies` and use [`the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category), [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category), or [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) to display categories.